# Creating search engine in different tables

Tags: php, mysql

What would you suggest to me, to use for searching in different tables for search engine ?

Each table is different from the other, columns are different and the number of rows are different.

Comment: Have you tried [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/)? Depending on your requirement it might be a good choice

Answer (score 0):

Create triggers on corresponding tables to fetch the content from different tables to a single table. Apply Full Text Search Indexing on that table.

Answer (score 0):

Create your function which will take dynamic inputs of column names and table name. For searching purpose you must know which column relate to which table then always pass these 2 params 1) table_name 2) column_names array to it. Create sql query with conditions where these params will fit and query will be developed dynamically. Then query will return result.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have considered `FULL-TEXT` Index mechanism in this case.
`FULL-TEXT` index is supported by `MyISAM` table `ENGINE` type.

`Full-text` searching is performed using MATCH() ... AGAINST syntax. MATCH() takes a comma-separated list that names the columns to be searched. AGAINST takes a string to search for, and an optional modifier that indicates what type of search to perform. The search string must be a literal string, not a variable or a column name. There are three types of full-text searches:

- A natural language search interprets the search string as a phrase in
  natural human language (a phrase in free text). There are no special
  operators. The stopword list applies. In addition, words that are
  present in 50% or more of the rows are considered common and do not
  match.

  Full-text searches are natural language searches if the IN NATURAL
  LANGUAGE MODE modifier is given or if no modifier is given.
- A boolean search interprets the search string using the rules of a special query language. The string contains the words to search for.
  It can also contain operators that specify requirements such that a
  word must be present or absent in matching rows, or that it should be
  weighted higher or lower than usual. Common words such as “some” or
  “then” are stopwords and do not match if present in the search
  string. The IN BOOLEAN MODE modifier specifies a boolean search. For
  more information, see Section 12.9.2, “Boolean Full-Text Searches”.
- A query expansion search is a modification of a natural language search. The search string is used to perform a natural language
  search. Then words from the most relevant rows returned by the search
  are added to the search string and the search is done again. The
  query returns the rows from the second search.

For more information refer this:

http://devzone.zend.com/26/using-mysql-full-text-searching/

http://www.iamcal.com/publish/articles/php/search/